# Search words in any order using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-sql

I have code to search the typed words from the text box, Get the typed word, search it in the web sql database and show the result in the HTML page.

In that i can search the word exactly as it is, using **LIKE**.

(i.e)

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE SearchWord LIKE %<typedword>%
```

If the table has,

1. Hello Doctor
2. Hi Sir
3. Hello World
4. Welcome Programmer

And the user types as "**Hello**", it shows me

```
**Hello** Doctor
**Hello** World
```

I need to display the result even if the user wrongly arranges the words,

i.e If the user types as "**World Hello**"

It is not showing any results.
But, I want to show the user

```
Hello World
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: You could simply create an OR for each word: `SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE SearchWord LIKE '%Hello%' OR SearchWord LIKE '%World%'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321128/search-words-in-any-order-using-backbonejs-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want an AND search using each of the words entered, rather than the exact string? Howabout something like this:

```
var yourSearchText = 'World Hello';
var searchTerms = yourSearchText.split(' ');
var searchTermBits = [];
for(var i=0; i<searchTerms.length;i++) {
        searchTermBits.push("word LIKE %"+searchTerms[i]+"%");
}

var result = searchTermBits.join(" AND ");
var query = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE '+result;
```

this will give you a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE '%world%' AND word LIKE '%hello%'
```

change the AND to an OR if you want to match any of the search terms rather than all.

Comment: Hey, I am not using PHP

Comment: Just Javascript and webSql

Comment: Updated answer with JavaScript. Please check

Comment: I Used OR instead of AND in join

Comment: Ya OR was perfect in your case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321128/search-words-in-any-order-using-backbonejs-collection