# Search words in any order using backboneJS collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have code to search the typed words from the text box, Get the typed word, search it in the collection and show the result in the HTML page.

In that i can search the word exactly as it is, using LIKE.

(i.e)

```
search: function(type,letters){
    var pattern = new RegExp(letters,"gi");
    return _(this.filter(function(data) {
        return pattern.test(data.get(type));
    }));
}
```

If the model has,

1. Hello Doctor
2. Hi Sir
3. Hello World
4. Welcome Programmer

And the user types as "Hello", it shows me

**Hello** Doctor
**Hello** World 
I need to display the result even if the user wrongly arranges the words,

i.e If the user types as "World Hello"

It is not showing any results. But, I want to show the user

Hello World

The same scenario is solved in web SQL. 
[Ref here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295205/search-words-in-any-order-using-js/)

I want to achieve this in the backboneJS collection.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your text on spaces and then iteratively filter the models and reduce them to the desired selection. For example:

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    search: function(type, letters) {
        var words = letters.split(/\s+/), //array of words
            models = _.clone(this.models); //copy of the models

        //for each word, check if it is found in the given attribute
        _.each(words, function(word) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(word, "i");
            models = _.filter(models, function(model) {
                return pattern.test(model.get(type));
            });
        });

        return models;
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/ha8RM/1/

Comment: what the **models** actually is? Is that a collection?

Comment: An array of models you can use to build a new collection if you want

Comment: Hey,this code skips the results. i.e If the letters matches 4 models, Hello world, Hello Human, Hello Earth, Hello user. Then it shows only Hello world and Hello Earth. It skips the alternatives

Comment: Modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/ha8RM/
It has **"Hello Doctor","Hello Sir","Hello World" and "Welcome Programmer"**
But if i search for hello, only `["Hello Doctor", "Hello World"]` is displayed

Comment: @PrabakaranRaja There was an incorrect g flag on the regexp. Corrected.

Comment: Can you please explain me what was the problem with that **g**?

Comment: Same regexp, multiple calls, and from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test : "test called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match". The regexp engine is then confused on what is the desired match